# Does bitcoin.conf allow multiple zmqpubhashblock settings?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf, zeromq, learning

If two programs both want to use the same bitcoin core instance to get notified about new blocks, do you add `zmqpubhashblock=<address>` *twice* to bitcoin.conf with two different port numbers, one for each program?

I have some "Meta" questions about this question too:

I suppose the answer to this question already exists somewhere and I spent some time trying to find it but failed.  What keywords would you use in a search engine to find the answer if it already exists online?  Is there a site where you'd expect this question to already have an answer, and if so, how would you find it?

Answer (score 1):

> do you add zmqpubhashblock= twice to bitcoin.conf with two different port numbers, one for each program?

Yes this is possible and mentioned in [doc/zmq.md](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/b05d3e76e7c72387b302cc21d420f31f384c8b10/doc/zmq.md)

*The socket type is PUB and the address must be a valid ZeroMQ socket address. The same address can be used in more than one notification. The same notification can be specified more than once.*

> What keywords would you use in a search engine to find the answer if it already exists online?
> Is there a site where you'd expect this question to already have an answer, and if so, how would you find it?

My approach for searching anything technical related to Bitcoin:

Add "Bitcoin Core" in things that are specific to Bitcoin Core. Copy whole error message if there is any. In your case it would be `"zmqpubhashblock" bitcoin core`

If search results in Google, DuckDuckGo etc. aren't helpful maybe search in different websites:

1. Bitcoin Stackexchange
2. Reddit
3. Bitcointalk
4. Github
5. Twitter

You can also search in Bitcoin Core IRC logs: https://bitcoin-irc.chaincode.com/bitcoin-core-dev/search?q=keyword